# SQL - filtering on a step by step basis

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I had this issue recently. I tried to remove lines with specific characters on a column name. I did this by creating several temporary tables as follows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tri1 as
SELECT * FROM loading WHERE postcode != 'n/a';

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tri2 as
SELECT * FROM tri1 WHERE postcode != '--';

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tri3 as
SELECT * FROM tri2 WHERE postcode != 'n-a';

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tri4 as
SELECT * FROM tri3 WHERE postcode != '99999';
```

This lengthy solution worked well.

However my first try was with this SQL query :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tri1 AS
SELECT * FROM loading WHERE (postcode != 'n/a' OR postcode != '--' OR postcode != 'n-a' OR postcode != '99999');
```

Issue is that I get less rows returned than when I'm doing a sequential cascade temporary table sorting like above.

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify the schema and give us some background on the problem?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, what kind of context do you need and what do you mean by schema? You mean schema like a table or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using so many temporary tables is not the way to go to solve your problem.  You were right to use just one query, but you got the logic wrong.  Here is the corrected query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tri1 AS
SELECT * FROM loading
WHERE (postcode != 'n/a' AND postcode != '--' AND postcode != 'n-a' AND postcode != '99999');
```

> Issue is that I get less returned rows than when I'm doing a sequential cascade temporary table

You were letting records slip through the cracks.  According to your logic, a record would have to have **all** of the conditions to be rejected.  For example, a record which had no '--' present would pass through, even though it had '99999'.

The logical rule governing the query I gave above is called **De Morgan's Law**, and you can [read about it here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeilsen I had this issue before. I'm never sure when to use the `or` or the `and`. I need to read more about De Morgan's law.